# SELinux - first attempt to restrict file by type - fails to fail

Tags: centos, permissions, selinux

I have a Centos 6 Linux box. I read tutorials on SELinux and wanted to try it out. Here are steps I followed,

1. set `SELINUX=enforcing` in `/etc/selinux/config`
2. turned on SELINUX with `setenforce 1`
3. `service httpd restart`
4. changed type on a php script file.

   from httpd_sys_content_t
      to something else eg: init_t (maybe this is not suitable type to test with?)

   chcon -t init_t /var/www/html/index.php

I hoped to get an error when I browsed to this file with web browser, but alas I was still able to see contents.

Comment: What was the SELinux configuration before you changed it to `enforcing`?

Comment: Relabel the whole system (`restorecon -r -v /`), reboot, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to relabel the whole system (this would be done with `touch /.autorelabel; reboot` instead of `restorecon`). Relabeling of /var/www/html using `restorecon -Fr /var/www/html` should be enough, then run your test again, assuming that yo did not change the file context of this directory using `semanage`.